# You have a lot on your plate

Tags: riddle

*What am I?*

> There is something fishy about me
>
> When I'm a mess I thread lightly
>
> I will never blow things out of proportion
>
> But you may not like what I have to tell you.

**Hint:**

> $$\underline{\Omega}$$

Comment: Is thread a typo or intentional?

Comment: It's intentional.

Comment: You're a scale I believe.

Comment: @John you might want to answer now it's been reopened

Comment: @bg6471, thank you! Put down a best guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're

> a scale.

There is something fishy about me

> Fish have scales

When I'm a mess I thread light

> Might reference mess hall where food might be rationed. Still sorting through this one.

I will never blow things out of proportion

> Scales by definition are proportionate.

But you may not like what I have to tell you

> Accurate and honest, even if you're overweight.

For the hint

> Can be a symbol used for Libra as scales.

Title

> A person who puts a lot on their plate may see an increase on the scale :). Can refer to the pan or plate that holds weights in a balance. It might also refer to an internal plate on a standard standing scale.

Comment: Oh wow, +1. I didn't realise that was the symbol for Libra.

Comment: That was fast -- almost all good, except for the title and the second one :)

Comment: for line #2 scale's anagram becomes laces, which may explain threading lightly

Comment: @BlueFire yes, that's it!